# Replace gnome screensaver with xscreensaver

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, screensaver

Under 17.10 (artful aardvark), installing xscreensaver produces some strange results including relaunching xcreensaver every 10 minutes. In some instances this spawns a new instance of xscreensaver savers. It appears that the gnome screensaver is causing this.

How do I remove (not disable) the gnome screensaver and install xscreensaver correctly?

(I found earlier answers but the last post was two years ago and the starting question was six years ago. They're probably no longer valid.)

Comment: "Old" doesn't necessarily mean it's an invalid answer, have you tried any of them? Also have you switched to Xorg from  the default Wayland? Not sure how good of an idea to use **x**screensaver under Wayland.

Comment: The original answers referred to points that I'm fairly sure don't apply to artful. That said, I installed 17.10 "out of the box" (no mods on my part). What's the best to sort out xorg vs. wayland? BTW, I'm seeing what looks very much like xscreensaver, with the "molecue" saver, resetting regularly, too. It doesn't leave additional processes behind, the way the rss-glx savers do. Either way, resetting strikes me as a Problem.